# deli Linux - how to use GUI

Tags: linux, gui

I've just installed Graphical Pulpit with deli Linux, but when I start my system I see only console. Is it fault of installation or I haven't typed something in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http://www.delilinux.org/wiki/doku.php?id=configuration:firststeps

You probably want to set up X to get a graphical display.